# rosdep install joy

Tags: ros, rosdep, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am trying to install the joy driver
i tried running the command rosdep install joy and got the following error what should I do?
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource joy
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/lab/ros_workspace
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35945/rosdep-install-joy/) by [gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2566/gupta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2566/gupta/) on 2012-06-07**:
i am running it on 12.04 and my /.bashrc ros_package_ path is as follows:                                     export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros:/home/lab/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you don't have the ROS joystick drivers installed. As a result, rosdep is unable to find the ROS package joy, and cannot resolve its system dependencies. You can test this by running the command:

```
rospack find joy
```

If you get an error, you can install joystick-drivers by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers
```

followed by

```
rosdep install joy
```

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-07**:
I'm having issues with this too. For some unknown reason, this doesn't work. I updated the rosdep sources, but the joy headers are still not recognized.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-06-07**:
Could you elaborate on your problem. Do you have the joystick-drivers stack installed? where does the failure appear?

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-08-09**:
I have a similar issue, except with several packages. I used 'sudo apt-get' to get them, and they display their locations when I do 'locate  ' but rosdep just returns "No Valid Packages or stacks listed as arguments" when I attempt to rosmake my package or do rosdep install

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-10**:
@jker: it seems like you have a different problem. I think your package is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH (i.e. ROS cannot locate it). With locally built code, you need to use a tool like rosinstall/rosws, or manually list package locations. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables